Is there a way to list directories, but ignore the last/base file in R?
I'm working with a directory that has close to 90,000 files inside 200 folders. With such a large number of files both list.files() and the list.dirs() functions are incredibly slow. The thing is I'm not even interested in the files just extracting the names of the folders and their directories.
for instance instead of returning
#images in 'folder1'
'/Users/name/Documents/project/folder1/Img_001.jpg'
'/Users/name/Documents/project/folder1/Img_002.jpg'

#images in 'folder2'
'/Users/name/Documents/project/folder2/Img_001.jpg'
'/Users/name/Documents/project/folder2/Img_002.jpg'

I just a want a list upto the individual folders as such:
'/Users/name/Documents/project/folder1/'
'/Users/name/Documents/project/folder2/'

Is there a way to do this upfront to cut down on time?

Yes, there is Bash!

How do you call list.files?

The actually directory is a lot more complicated and I'll be working in chunks so I have the start of the file saved to an object so list files looks something like
list.files(path = start.file, recursive = T


I can work with either a list or character vector at the moment

shell("dir /s /b /o:n /ad")?

This will list the full path of the jpg files in folders directly under project and then take just the directory part and then find the unique ones:
Sys.glob("/Users/name/Documents/project/*/*.jpg") |> dirname() |> unique()

This will list directories (not files) immediately under project regardless of what they contain or do not contain.  The -1 is to omit project itself.
list.dirs("/Users/Louis/Downloads/project/")[-1]


fs::dir_ls() comes with a type arg and at least on Windows it's ~6x faster than list.dirs() when testing on a conda cache directory:
p_ = "D:/pkg_cache/micromamba/"

tictoc::tic("fs::dir_ls")
fs_dir_ls <- fs::dir_ls(path = p_, type= "directory", recurse = TRUE, all = TRUE)
tictoc::toc()
#> fs::dir_ls: 0.36 sec elapsed
str(fs_dir_ls)
#>  'fs_path' Named chr [1:7234] "D:/pkg_cache/micromamba/.micromamba" ...
#>  - attr(*, "names")= chr [1:7234] "D:/pkg_cache/micromamba/.micromamba" "D:/pkg_cache/micromamba/.micromamba/condabin" "D:/pkg_cache/micromamba/.micromamba/envs" "D:/pkg_cache/micromamba/.micromamba/envs/d2147d81" ...

tictoc::tic("list.dirs")
lst_dirs <- list.dirs(path = p_)
tictoc::toc()
#> list.dirs: 2.33 sec elapsed
str(lst_dirs)
#>  chr [1:7235] "D:/pkg_cache/micromamba/" ...

Difference is result lengths comes from the first element, list.dirs() includes starting path while fs::dir_ls() does not.
